# No network device available on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

I just installed linux 16.04 LTS on my computer (not a dual boot), and it was working just fine, but suddenly, the WiFi stopped working. I tried several things I found that might have helped (finding drivers and trying to install them, several other similar things) but nothing worked and I'm stuck.

`iwconfig` returns no wireless extension.
Here is what i get for `lspci -vv`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 255
    Region 0: Memory at b4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [40] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr+ NoSnoop+ FLReset-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L1, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 <32us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range B, TimeoutDis+, LTR+, OBFF Via WAKE#
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 16ms to 55ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR+, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Device Serial Number c0-b6-f9-ff-ff-f5-ae-a6
    Capabilities: [14c v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 3145728ns
        Max no snoop latency: 3145728ns
    Capabilities: [154 v1] L1 PM Substates
        L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
              PortCommonModeRestoreTime=30us PortTPowerOnTime=60us
```

Comment: Did you happen to update the kernel? If so, does rebooting into the previous one help?

Comment: If this is a laptop, sometimes there is a tiny little switch or button that turns the Wifi On and off. You may have accidentally tapped it.

Comment: What does `sudo rfkill list all` return?

Comment: No I did not update the kernel

Comment: well it is a laptop with a switch on and off button but it's not working since I switchted to ubuntu (volume does though).

Comment: and sudo rfkill list all returns nothing

Comment: @djo from your pci list, it's clear what device you have. But it's not clear whether or not you have a working driver. If you see no output from `rfkill list all` it means you have no working wireless network interface. What driver did you try to install? Is `iwlwifi` module correctly loaded? You can find this by running `lsmod | grep iwlwifi`.

Comment: Also look for any messages printed in `dmesg` about this module. Run the command `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` and let us know what is the output of that.

Comment: So I tried lsmod | grep iwlwifi and dmesg | grep iwlwifi but both return nothing. and before i tried to install iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.30.14.0 that I found on the intel website, not sure it worked though...

Comment: Could you load it by `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`?

Comment: I get:  sudo modprobe iwlwifi
[sudo] password for *****: 
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

Comment: That’s really weird. iwlwifi is part of the Linux kernel. Something is seriously wrong. Can you update your kernel with `sudo apt install linux-generic`? Btw, the ucode file you downloaded from Intel goes in `/lib/firmware`, but most recent kernels already have this.

Comment: Well I guess I need an internet connection to update the kernel. How can I do this without it? I tried copying an iso of ubuntu on a usb (not a boot) and mount it as a cd, it worked but the software & updates app never recognised it as a cd and was not able to update from it... And for the intel ucode file I did copy it in /lib/firmware

Comment: Oh and wifi or usb are the only options since i don't have an ethernet port or a cd player on this computer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, your Linux kernel is missing the module `iwlwifi` which is the primary driver for Intel wireless devices. It's likely this issue will be resolved if you update your kernel. In order to do that, you will need a temporary internet connection. If your phone has internet, you could use USB to tether the connection to your laptop. You could also use a USB to Ethernet adapter. To update the kernel run the following command

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

---

If you have **absolutely no way** to connect this computer to internet, here's how to update your kernel to a more recent one with a USB stick. First head over to https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ to pick up the latest build of the kernel 4.4 (this is what's being recommended by `linux-generic` in my 16.04 vm). As of now, it is [v4.4.202](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.202/). Under where it says "Build for amd64 succeeded", you will download four files:

- [linux-headers-4.4.202-0404202_4.4.202-0404202.201911160550_all.deb](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.202/linux-headers-4.4.202-0404202_4.4.202-0404202.201911160550_all.deb)
- [linux-headers-4.4.202-0404202-generic_4.4.202-0404202.201911160550_amd64.deb](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.202/linux-headers-4.4.202-0404202-generic_4.4.202-0404202.201911160550_amd64.deb)
- [linux-image-unsigned-4.4.202-0404202-generic_4.4.202-0404202.201911160550_amd64.deb](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.202/linux-image-unsigned-4.4.202-0404202-generic_4.4.202-0404202.201911160550_amd64.deb)
- [linux-modules-4.4.202-0404202-generic_4.4.202-0404202.201911160550_amd64.deb](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.202/linux-modules-4.4.202-0404202-generic_4.4.202-0404202.201911160550_amd64.deb)

and save them to a USB stick. Next, copy them over to your laptop in a directory, go to terminal, browse to that directory, and run

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

And restart your computer. In grub menu, under Advanced Options for Ubuntu, you should now see that 4.4.202 as an option, and when you boot into desktop, you should have a working `iwlwifi` module. If it is not automatically loaded, you can load it by `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`. Once you are connected, you can now install `linux-generic` which will automatically update your default kernel.

Comment: Well i ended up reinstalling ubuntu completely and its working now. Thank you very much for your help!